# How to change the description that shows up in Google and add search tags to your page?

Tags: html, search, opensearchdescription

For example google's page shows a description:
[image]
In their case the text is

> Search the world's information, including webpages, images, video's
>   and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly
>   what you're looking ...

I've looked at the source of their page to find how this text is determined but could find nothing. Google also has a [nice page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) explaining how to make descriptions, but never specify where to put the description.

Someone told me the description should be in the robots.txt, but when looking at the [specification](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt?hl=en) of robots.txt it only has four keywords:
- user-agent (start of group)
- disallow (only valid as a group-member record)
- allow (only valid as a group-member record)
- sitemap (non-group record)

None of them are description or search tags.

Comment: If you read that _nice page_ link one more time, you'll find how-to in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet is often taken from the description meta tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, video's and more." />
```

which is placed between the page's `<head> </head>` tags.

What actually shows to the user is completely at the discretion of Google's algorithms - it may decide that another section of text on that page is more relevant to the user's search.

Answer (score 1):

In my websites I put the following inside the `<head>` tag of your home page (HTML).

```
<meta name="description" content="Enter your description of your website here!" />
```

[Here is another article by google further explaining this.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)